# tshark can't capture the TLS connections with Apollo

Tags: ssl, tcp, wireshark, apollo

I enabled TLS support for Apollo and sent the messages with TLS to Apollo server. In the backend of Apollo, it shows that it received the TLS messages.

However, when i tried to capture the traffic with tshark, there is only TCP handshakes information like SYN,ACK,PUSH,RST etc. but has no SSL handshakes.

is it because tshark can't capture the ssl traffic?